# How to translate this Python partition code to C++?

Tags: c++, python

I have this algorithm for generating the partitions of n:

```python
def partitions(n):
    if n == 0:
        yield []
        return
    for p in partitions(n-1):
        yield [1] + p
        if p and (len(p) < 2 or p[1] > p[0]):
            yield [p[0] + 1] + p[1:]
```

However I am not sure how to even go about translating this to C++, mostly because I don't know the shorthand equivalents for yield functionality or substring slices or list concatenations, etc. What's the most straightforward translation?

Comment: The simplest translation is a vector and eager evaluation.  Whether that's an option depends on how big `n` gets.  Past a certain point, you're probably gonna have to build a state machine.

Comment: @cHao Not sure I understand what you mean by that

Comment: What i mean is, rather than using `yield` to generate the elements one by one, figure them all immediately and add them to a `std::vector` that you then return.  If `n` is too big, though, that won't be feasible.

Comment: So you're saying to make it iterative, not recursive?

Comment: Recursion, `yield`-alikes, and C++ don't get along well.  Any two together work fine, but all three together are just all kinds of ugly.  If you want the functionality of `yield`, you'll want your function iterative, as a deeper call stack == more crap to have to keep track of.  If you don't care, just use a vector and add stuff to it.

Comment: So basically this (accelAsc) http://homepages.ed.ac.uk/jkellehe/partitions.php where instead of yield, I append to a list and then return that list at the end. Then translate all that to C++

Comment: Or, basically *what you have right now*, and instead of yielding, you add to a list.  Either works, though the iterative version is less likely to kill your stack for huge `n`s.

Comment: I understand how to translate the recursive now, just making the iterative. So far I've got it all translated except for stuff like yield a[:k + 2] which I've already translated into myList.append(a[:k+2]) -- not sure what the C++ equivalent is for a[:k+2]

Comment: Something like `std::vector(a.begin(), a.begin() + k + 2)`?  Or `std::vector(&a[0], &a[k+2])`?  You might need to add one to the end; i don't remember whether/which range endpoints are inclusive in Python.

Comment: Yeah that's exactly what I tried, too -- gave the error "error: missing template arguments before '(' token"

Comment: had to do vector<long long>(a.begin(), a.begin() + k + 2)

Answer (score 0):

I slightly edited BLUEPIXY's answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10716324/partition-function-in-c) post for your convenience.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void save(std::vector<std::vector<int> > & dest, std::vector<int> const & v, int level){
    dest.push_back(std::vector<int>(v.begin(), v.begin() + level + 1));
}

void partition(int n, std::vector<int> & v, std::vector<std::vector<int> > & dest, int level = 0){
    int first; /* first is before last */
    if(0 == n){
        return;
    }
    v[level] = n;
    save(dest, v, level);

    first = (level == 0) ? 1 : v[level - 1];

    for(int i = first; i <= (n / 2); ++i){
        v[level] = i; /* replace last */
        partition(n - i, v, dest, level + 1);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    int N = 30;

    std::vector<int> vec(N);
    std::vector<std::vector<int> > partitions;
    // You could change N * N to minimize the number of relocations
    partitions.reserve(N * N);

    partition(N, vec, partitions);

    std::cout << "Partitions: " << partitions.size() << std::endl;
    for(std::vector<std::vector<int> >::iterator pit = partitions.begin(); pit != partitions.end(); ++pit) {
        std::cout << '[';
        for(std::vector<int>::iterator it = (*pit).begin(); it != (*pit).end(); ++it) {
            std::cout << *it << '\t';
        }
        std::cout << ']' << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output on [ideone](http://ideone.com/xTml8P)